# Do MVC controllers save state?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is it appropriate in the MVC pattern for a controller to save state in any way.

Note, I realize that controllers do not save state on ASP.Net. I'm not using ASP.Net. I'm wanting to know if that pattern restricts this or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern would have you save the state to the Model/models, not the Controller. The controller *could* modify the state, or the model could contain internals to modify it's own state.

Comment: That is what I wanted to know. Thank you.